# How do you cache results processed by a celery application

Tags: python-3.x, caching, redis, celery

I want to find out whether it is possible to cache results sent to a `celery` application. For example, suppose I have a basic celery application which looks like:

`tasks.py`

```
import os
from celery import Celery
import time

redis_url = 'redis://localhost:6379'
app = Celery('tasks', backend=redis_url, broker=redis_url)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(10) # Added to see whether caching occurs.
    return x + y
```

If I call the function `add` twice with the same arguments as in here:

```
from tasks import add

add.delay(10, 10)
add.delay(10, 10)
```

Will the second argument be computed faster? Possibly because the input output pair `((10, 10), 20)` is already available in the result backend? If not, how do I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Whatever calls `add.delay(10, 10)` should do the caching (memoize)...

Comment: Thanks Dejan. Is it possible to configure the result backend to cache as well. Since redis already an LRU based cache, can I use that?

Comment: Not that I know of. Nothing guarantees that calling a function with same parameter returns same result. Languages like D (dlang.org) have notion of function purity and can do the optimisation you would like to have in Python... Python will probably never be able to guarantee that.